# Auto margins with tabs in bootstrap 5

Tags: css, tabs, auto, margins, bootstrap-5

I'm learning to use bootstrap 5, so bear with me if this question seems a bit basic!

I'm toying around with tabs to generate tabbable panes of local content. I've used the code provided in the documentation here :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

And it works perfectly. It responds well also to justify-content, so the tabs are easy to center or distribute. Exactly what I am looking for.

But, I can't make them split with auto margins (mr-auto and ml-auto) so that, for example, the first two tabs will be aligned on the left and the last one on the right. When I include them in the ul tag, it is just ignored (while the justify-content work just fine)

I'm looking to do something like in the flex documentation :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins
or in Wikipedia where the article and talk tabs are on the left, and the read, edit and history are on the right.
How could I do that?

Comment: No need to warn us about the question being basic or not. You're welcome to ask it either way.  Could you edit your question to remove the first paragraph and maybe mention that your question is about Bootstrap 5 somewhere else in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your last `li` like :

```
<li class="nav-item ms-auto" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
  </li>
```

In Bootstrap 5,

- t - for classes that set margin-top or padding-top
- b - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom
- s - for classes that set margin-left or padding-left in LTR, margin-right or padding-right in RTL
- e - for classes that set margin-right or padding-right in LTR, margin-left or padding-* left in RTL
- x - for classes that set both *-left and *-right
- y - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom
- blank - for classes that set a margin or padding on all 4 sides of the element

For More Info : [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was following the documentation too closely and didn't realized s would do the trick , I was too focused on r and l. Thanks again!